# Gap and Island Grouping

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, difference

For my source table I have all the “Contact history for customers” in the correct order (ascending starting from earliest date at the top).  What I need to do is group rows where the contacts are related to the same issue. The way to determine whether a issue is related to each other is based on the time. If the time difference <2 weeks then the two cases are related.

A 1 in the 'Pass or Fail' column highlights whether the case was fully resolved. A 0 indicates that the call from the below row is related to the same issue.

I need to produce a summary of this table to show where a customer has contacted multiple times against the same query

I am using SQL Server 2012

Here is an example of my source data. In my full table I will have multiple customers.  You can see I have colour coded to show that there are a total of 9 contacts but just 4 different issues. There will be no fixed number of contacts or issues for each customer
[image]

| Customer_ID | start_date | Next_Date | Time_Difference_(Mins) | total_contacts | Pass_or_fail | NEXT_Contact_same_day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 03/03/2022 | 05/05/2022 | 90794 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 12345 | 05/05/2022 | 05/05/2022 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 12345 | 05/05/2022 | 06/05/2022 | 1409 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 12345 | 06/05/2022 | 06/05/2022 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 12345 | 06/05/2022 | 06/05/2022 | 11 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 12345 | 06/05/2022 | 20/11/2022 | 284973 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 12345 | 20/11/2022 | 05/01/2023 | 66242 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 12345 | 05/01/2023 | 05/01/2023 | 178 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 12345 | 05/01/2023 | NULL | NULL | 1 | 1 | 0 |

I have tried using DENSE_RANK, ROW_NUMBER, LAG&LEAD on the Pass or Fail column, as well as MAX & MIN dates for the start and next dates, but am not having any luck.

E.g.

```
select Customer ID, sum(total_contacts), min(Start date), max(Next Date)
from (select *,
             sum(case when Pass or fail = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by Customer ID) as grp
      from #Mastery
     ) #Mastery
where total_contacts = '1'
group by Customer ID, grp;
```

-- this returns all contacts

```
select Customer ID, sum(total_contacts) AS total_Contacts, SUM (Pass or fail) AS Pass#, min(Start date) AS Mindate, max(Next Date) AS Maxdate, 
       ROW_NUMBER () over(partition by Customer ID order by Pass or fail) as Contactranking
from  #Mastery2
group by Customer ID,  Pass or fail
```

-- this just returns the sum of passes and fails

This is the output I am looking for. You can see that against the same customer ID I have 4 rows, one row represents each issue. For each Row it should show the number of calls against the issue. To quantify the number of calls related to the same issue you have to use the 'Pass or Fail' column
[image]

Comment: How do you determine what goes into each color group?

Comment: You'll need to use the 'Pass or fail' column. 

A Zero in the column shows that the case is not finished. It is only finished when the sequence of Zero's ends in a 1. 

The first row is a single query because the 'Pass or fail' column ends in a 1.

From row 2 to 5 its all Zero's so those new contacts are related. In row 6 it shows that the case was finally resolved because the 'pass or fail' column now has a 1.

Comment: Looks like the first thing is finding a way to assign groups to each row using a window function, likely a RANK. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Maybe use LAG/LEAD on Pass or Fail, add prev and current column, and order the date by DESC. Meaning, you start backwards from the pass (1). Keep adding to the fails (0). Everytime it encounters a Pass, that will signal a new group.

Comment: Slight detour but still important. You state you are using sql server 2012. You need to get an upgrade path sorted out. That version has been out of support for more than a year now.

Comment: Please don't use images for data, use tabular text

Comment: Thanks @drum. Please could you give some more detail on the 'keep adding to the fails (0) Everytime it encounters a Pass, that will signal a new group.'

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps and island style problem where you have the right idea about the grouping, but there are some details that makes this a bit tricker. Here's a potential solution:

```sql
SELECT  CustomerID, MIN(startDate) startDate, NULLIF(MAX(nextDate), '99991231') nextDate, COUNT(*) cnt
FROM    (
    select  *
    ,   SUM(passprev) OVER(partition by customerid order by startDate, nextdate) AS grp
    from (
        
        select  LAG(passorfail, 1, 0) over(partition by customerid order by d.startDate,  d.nextDate) AS passprev
        ,   d.*
        ,   customerID
        from (
            VALUES  (12345, N'03/03/2022', N'05/05/2022', N'90794', 1, 1, 0)
            ,   (12345, N'05/05/2022', N'05/05/2022', N'3', 1, 0, 1)
            ,   (12345, N'05/05/2022', N'06/05/2022', N'1409', 1, 0, 0)
            ,   (12345, N'06/05/2022', N'06/05/2022', N'2', 1, 0, 1)
            ,   (12345, N'06/05/2022', N'06/05/2022', N'11', 1, 0, 1)
            ,   (12345, N'06/05/2022', N'20/11/2022', N'284973', 1, 1, 0)
            ,   (12345, N'20/11/2022', N'05/01/2023', N'66242', 1, 1, 0)
            ,   (12345, N'05/01/2023', N'05/01/2023', N'178', 1, 0, 1)
            ,   (12345, N'05/01/2023', NULL, NULL, 1, 1, 0)
        ) t (CustomerID,Startdate,NextDate,[TimeDifference(Mins)],total_contacts,Passorfail,[NEXT_Contact_same_day])
        CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT  CONVERT(DATETIME, startdate, 103) AS startDate
                ,   ISNULL(CONVERT(DATETIME, NextDate, 103), '99991231') AS nextDate
            ) d
        ) x
    ) x
GROUP BY customerID, grp
```

First and foremost, the problem is that you have to get the previous `passorfail` column, because usually when you create a gaps and islands sum, you want to keep the value at 0, until a new group arrives, while here, 1 creates a new group. Therefore I use `LAG(passorfail, 1, 0)`.

The sorting here is also a bit tricky, because you have multiple duplicates dates. For this, I create the tiebreaker by `ISNULL(CONVERT(DATETIME, NextDate, 103), '99991231')` so the open dates goes to the end. It also simplifies the MAX handling later.

The rest is nothing special, except we flip back the date to null with `NULLIF(MAX(nextDate), '99991231')`

Just a few notes: you should really provide the test data in table format. Also, DD/MM/YYYY is a very unhandy date style to work with, YYYYMMDD is much nicer.

Comment: Wow, thanks very much for the speedy response. I'll take some time to digest and work through. Cheers